# Not sure how to enforce a specific formatting of a string variable in java

Tags: java, string

I'm currently working on an assignment that has me taking an input from the user, and pulling matching information from a csv file. However, I need that information to be formatted a certain way, so that it can even be properly searched for in the csv file. I'm using IllegalArgumentExceptions to enforce this, alongside if statements. Right now I'm working taking dates as an input, and want to take it in either a MM/DD/YYYY format, or a MM/DD/YY format. I'm just not sure how to even go about this, and am hoping to have a pointer or two. I'm looking to implement this as part of a constructor in the Date class I made for my program, shown below.

```
public Date(String date) {
        if(date == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("please provide a date in the format of MM/DD/YY or MM/DD/YYYY");
        }
    }
```

My initial thought would be to test for each individual segment of the string, but it'd be a pain to break it up into months, days, and years, then convert each section into an integer and make sure it's not past the logical limit (no more than 12 months, no more than 31 days, etc.). I'm really just looking to see if I can receive some guidance on a much more efficient way of enforcing it remains in the format stated previously.

Comment: Sounds like a job for regex or trying to parse the date string passed in.

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE, are there any additional steps I will have to take to be able to import regex?

Comment: regex = regular expression. Regular expressions weren't originally in Java, but they've been available as part of java.lang package for a couple of decades now... Your question is a little open ended because you haven't indicated how dates were being input, i.e. do  you have a UI that prevents users from making mistakes that you have to clean up later? That's where you should be starting.

Comment: The idea is that if users input anything outside of the date format, then it'll trigger an IllegalArgumentException, apologies for not articulating on that! I'm still getting used to how specific you have to be with coding in general, it's a pain with how many different ways there are to interpret things haha

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, date-time values when stored in text should be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. For a date-only value, that would be YYYY-MM-DD.

As for your `Date` class, don’t invent one. Use the class given to you, `java.time.LocalDate`.

Since you have non-standard inputs, define a pair of `DateTimeFormatter` objects to match each of the formats you expect.

```
DateTimeFormatter longer = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter shorter = … ;
```

For each input, attempt to parse.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , longer ) ;
```

When making that attempt, use a try-catch to trap for `DateTimeParseException`.

Repeat for the shorter formatter. If both throw the exception, you have unexpected faulty input.

Before parsing, test for a `null` with `Objects.requireNonNull`. That method throws an exception if null.

And you can test to see if your input is either empty (no characters) or if all the characters are whitespace.

```
if ( input.isBlank() ) { … }
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response, but thank you very much! I appreciate you informing me the formatting I should be using, and while I'll absolutely use that in the future, for now, it's more a case of how the assignment wants me to format it. Still, this helps me a lot!

Comment: @Mr.Moffia When posting amount schoolwork/homework, make a note of that fact.